# obtaining Groovy map value by key

Tags: groovy

I'm a complete groovy noob, I have this simple map:

```
def BranchToPort = [
    [branch: 'master'   , port: 15565],
    [branch: 'Release'  , port: 15566],
    [branch: 'Feature'  , port: 15567],
    [branch: 'Prototype', port: 15568],
    [branch: 'HotFix'   , port: 15569]
]
```

and given a branch name (the key) I want to obtain the port number, preferably in a single line of code. Bizarrely there are a ton of examples across the internet for obtaining the key based on its corresponding value, but not the other way around.

Comment: You should name your variables starting with lowercase chars. There are places, the groovy parser will assume a class instead and you end up getting really weird errors.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming the branch names are unique, you can write a simple method to return the port for a given branch name

```
def port(String branchName) {
    BranchToPort.find { it['branch'] ==  branchName }?.get("port")
}
```

Just to explain what is going on here as you mentioned *"I'm a complete groovy noob"*

- `def port(String branchName)` here we are declaring a method which takes a string value `branchName`
- `BranchToPort.find` because BranchToPort is a `groovy collection` we can use `.find` which takes a closure, represented by the curly braces. This closure will execute on every item in the collection and the functionality of `find` is that it will return the first *matching* item.
- `it['branch'] ==  branchName` this is our "*get me the first item that matches this condition*" inside of our closure. The item in the collection is referenced using `it`. Here we are accessing the `"branch"` key and checking if the value matches the input `branchName`.
- <s>`}['port']` finally the key is accessed to extract just the value.</s>
- `?.get("port")` *edited after comment by Royg*. We use the safe null checker `?` and attempt to access the "port" value. The `?` will prevent a null pointer exception.

One last note, in Groovy methods will return the last executed statement so there is no need to use `return` or assign the statement in the method to a variable.

hope this helps.

[edit]
Forgot to put an example of calling the method:

```
portNumber = port("master")
assert portNumber == 15565
> True
```

Comment: Change the find to: `BranchToPort.find { it['branch'] ==  branchName }?.get("port")`. By doing so, you'll not get NPE on a non-existing branch.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, you don't have *a* Map, you have a List of two-entry Maps. If you would like to create a single Map with branch names for the keys and port numbers as the corresponding values, you can do this:

```
def branchPorts = BranchToPort.collectEntries { [it.branch, it.port] }
```

[The `collectEntries` method](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/lang/Iterable.html#collectEntries(groovy.lang.Closure)) does the magic here, as it goes through each item in the List, transforms each element according to the provided closure argument, and appends the closure result to a Map instance, which is ultimately returned by the method.

The closure, `{ [it.branch, it.port] }`, does the transformation; it turns each Map in the List into a two element List itself. The first element of the List represents the key of the Map entry (the branch name) and the second the value of the Map entry (the port).

Once you have the map created, getting the port is a standard Map lookup using the branch name as the key:

```
assert branchPorts['master'] == 15565
assert branchPorts['HotFix'] == 15569
```